# div element flashes when adjusting visibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, visibility

I would like to hide a div when a button is clicked and show it when a link is clicked, but what is happening is it simply blinks, whether showing it or hiding it. It does this no matter what way I try to change its visibility on the page: changing top:-1000px; to top:0px; or visibility: hidden to visibility: visible or using the display "" vs "none" attributes. All these cause it to appear (if making visible) for a flash, or disappear (if making hidden) for a flash.

I'm calling a JS function when clicking a link to show the div, and calling a JS function when submitting the form in the div to hide the div again.

Any clue why this could happen?

A few points about the page that might be relevant:

-some elements are drawn via Javascript during onLoad for the Body{}, but not those containing this element, or this element itself.

-this

```
<script language="JavaScript" src = "dashboard.js">
    </script>
```

...is called in the head section, and includes the below functions

-I've also tried putting the hide/show functions directly following the relevant div in the html code, but no change.

.css for the div:

```
    div#userRegistration{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 20;
    top: -1000px;
}
```

JS function to show - updated per below:

```
function userRegistration(){
   document.getElementById("userRegistration").style.top = '0px';
   return true;
}
```

JS function to hide (note this never gets used unless I can get the div to show up and stay in the first place) - updated:

```
function validateUserRegistration(){
    document.getElementById("userRegistration").style.display = 'none';
    return true;
}
```

the updated HTML (per 2 suggestions below):

```
        <div id="userRegistration">
            <h3>New User Registration:</h3>
            <form style="text-align: left;" action="" onsubmit="return validateUserRegistration();">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Email:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="userName"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            User Name:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="userName"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Password:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" name="password"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Repeat Password:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" name="repeatPassword"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" name="submitRegistration" value="Submit"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

EDIT: The empty href="" below reloading the page is what was causing the "flash". Thanks to techtheatre for bringing this to my attention. /EDIT

HTML that initially shows the div (does the same flashy-thing as when trying to hide the div if it is already visible on page load):

```
<div id="newUser">
   <a href="" onclick="return userRegistration();">

     New User? Register here.

   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: On the onSubmit="validateUserRegistration()" in the form, try putting onSubmit="return validateUserRegistration();"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `return true;` to the end of both of your functions inside the brace

**EDIT:**

one other thing...what is supposed to happen when you submit the form?  You have left the action blank.  If it submits back to this same page (which is what it does with the current HTML), your whole page will reload.  This would make it hide for an instant, and then reappear when the page reloads.  If you are trying to submit your form data without a page reload, you will need to implement this in an AJAX call...

Comment: and you did that in combination with the change suggested by @william ?... The combination of his and my response should have this humming along beautifully.

Comment: Ok, so I combined both of your suggestions, and it is now working in IE, but not in Firefox or G Chrome. Thanks for the help so far. Any idea why IE and not Firefox/Chrome?

Comment: Reply to Edit: Yes, I will be implementing an AJAX call later, but just for testing purposes I'm having it reload the page. The div is now disappearing like I expect it to when clicking 'Submit', but only in IE. I don't think this is causing the problem in Firefox/Chrome because it also happens when trying to show the div, before the form/submit button even appears.

Comment: Fixed. Having the empty href="" was causing the flash, as you noticed with the submit action being empty. Thank you!!